# How to get the content of an existing apex class using metadata api

Tags: metadata-api, java

I was able to get the names of all the apex classes in an org using metadata api with Java

```
public void getApexClasses() throws ConnectionException {
    ListMetadataQuery[] queries = new ListMetadataQuery[1];

    ListMetadataQuery queryApexClass = new ListMetadataQuery();
    queryApexClass.setType("ApexClass");

    queries[0] = queryApexClass;

    FileProperties[] fileProperties = mConnection.listMetadata(queries, 29.0);
    for(FileProperties fileProperty : fileProperties) {
        System.out.println(fileProperty.getType() + ":" + fileProperty.getFullName());
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to get the content of each of these apex classes. How can I do that?

```
ApexClass apexClass = new ApexClass();
// Some code to load the apexClass instance - HELP required
System.out.println(apexClass.getContent());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options for this...

- **Metadata API**, once **Spring'14** is rolled out (this month) you can use the new [readMetadata](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_readMetadata.htm) operation on the Metadata API to retrieve the ApexClass.
- **[Partner API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/) and SOQL**, you can currently use **SOQL** to actually query (via the [query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_query.htm) operation) the Body field on this object, e.g.

  ```
  Select Id, Name, Body From ApexClass
  ```
- **[Tooling API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm) and SOQL**, this also allows you to [query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/intro_soap_overview.htm) as above with the Partner API

**Note:** These later two options leverage the fact that the [ApexClass](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm) object is an standard object and thus queryable via SOQL. The Body field will be null if the class resides in a managed package.